# HDMI to plasma tv

Tags: display, hdmi, display-resolution

I am trying to connect my cheap low end Gateway laptop to a large panisonic plasma TV using HDMI.

My issue is I can not get it to display correctly.

My laptop is running Chromixium , which is Ubuntu under a googleish GUI.

The laptop does not appear to have either nvidia or ati, just some budget Intel onboard.

I have tried using the graphical monitor setup app that comes with the OS, it is able to turn the hdmi monitor on, but it displays wrong. Since the laptop screen is smaller than the TV, it puts my task bar and all of my apps in only about 60% of the TV, the rest is useable, but it acts like a desktop extension.

To be clear I want to just clone everything I see on the laptop to the TV. I do not want to extent of have shared desktop.

I have tried hundreds of permutations of xrand in console, some have looked better, but not one worked.

When i used to just plug this in on win 7&10 it would just work, on my Samsung I had a wonderful little app to play with it and make ajustments.

Why is this so hard? Is there a program I can get? Something to treat it like a projector and not like a VGA display/additional monitor?

If it helps the laptop screen is native 1366x768 and I believe the TV should be 1080p.

Comment: Not off topic. It is about the operating system Ubuntu and this is "askubuntu.com"

Comment: We're all Debian here people, let's get along and be helpful.

Comment: to all of those complaining about this not being ubuntu, take a swift look at this [https://www.chromixium.org/](https://www.chromixium.org/)

Answer (score 0):

When you have your HDMI cable connected to your laptop, have you tried to press `Dash`(windows key) + `P`? On my ubuntu 16.04 it cycles through the different screen modes.

You might have to go to the audio settings, and select HDMI output because in my system the sound is not automatically redirected to the HDMI port.

Comment: I have not tried that, but I will. Thank you.